# Evaluating $\int \frac{L}{E-iR}\operatorname d i$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Can someone please explain to me step by step, how to evaluate this integral? $E$, $R$ and $L$ are constants.

$$\int \frac{L}{E-iR}di$$

The result should be:  $-\frac{L}{R}\ln(E-iR) + C$

Thank you.

Comment: Have you learned about substitution? Try $iR = Eu$

Comment: @rubick, try putting $E-iR=u$

Comment: I tried it, but now I realized I made error. I was integrating $u$ instead of doing $\frac{du}{di}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

let $ u = E - iR$, then $\dfrac{du}{di} = -R \rightarrow  du = - R \,di$

Then

$$ \int \frac{L}{E - iR} \ di = \frac{L}{-R}\displaystyle\int \frac{-R}{E - iR} \ di $$
$$= \frac{L}{-R} \int \frac{1}{u} \ du = \frac{L}{-R} (\ln (u) + C)$$
$$ = \frac{L}{-R} (\ln (E - iR) + C) =\frac{L}{-R} (\ln (E - iR)     +   K $$